# To find the substring from string without library.I know its an easy one but i cant find where I am getting struck with that if statement

Tags: java, string

```
package stringoperation;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stringops {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String string ;
        String sub ; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter a string");
        string =in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter a substring to identify");
        sub = in.nextLine();

        char[] array= string.toCharArray(); // converting string to array of char
        char[] subarray  = sub.toCharArray();  //converting sub string to array of char 
        int count=0;
        for(int  j=0;j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if(array[j]==subarray[count]) //till both are same it will run
            {
                if(count==sub.length()-1) //if substring size is reached thats mean matched break out
                {
                    System.out.println("substring is present");
                    break;
                }

                j++;                     
            }

            if(array[j]!=subarray[count]) // otherwise make count as 0 to proceed again 
            {
                count=0;
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

The `if` statement I checked still can't find the error. I am missing something. Just tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where are you incrementing `count`?

Comment: You're incrementing 'j' twice if you found your first match. This will skip a character from the array.

Comment: Try looking at the length of your substring and check that it isn't terminated with a newline character. (I'm unsure whether these are appended to input data when using `nextLine`, but it would definitely affect your comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string.indexOf(sub) != -1`, after you're certain that the input strings are in the format you expect; i.e. control characters such as newlines aren't appended to your input data. It's necessary to keep in mind that comparisons will be failed if the Strings you're comparing don't match *exactly*, i.e.

```
"example" != "Example".
```